# How to refresh page until alert is not visible using selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I’m trying to make web automation software using selenium and python and i want to solve one problem.

The problem is that the code is stop when chrome alert is visible like ‘You can’t buy this product right now. Try again later.”

So what i want is refresh page until alert is not visible.

i try using `driver.switch_to.alert()`, but i can’t solve the problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This below code should get the job done.

**Explanation :-**

Basically you need a `while infinite loop`, and a `try-except`.

in `try` when the `alert is not visible`, what the code should do. and if it `fails` then it will go to `except`, because, in that case `Alert` must be `visible` and that's the reason it **did not** `execute` the `code` written in try.

`Except` is very simple to understand, just a print statement, followed by, a `refresh` cause that is your `requirement`. and a time.sleep(4) to let the page refresh again.

```
while(True):
    try:
        # do what you wanna do here when alert is not visible.
        # When alert is not present, then code here what exactly you wanna do. 
        break
    except:
        print("Alert must be visible here")
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

everything is very simple than you think, you don't even need to set time. sleep()
[https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=refresh#:~:text=driver.quit()-,refresh,-()%C2%B6](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=refresh#:%7E:text=driver.quit()-,refresh,-()%C2%B6)

set an expectation [https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#:~:text=driver%2C%2010](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#:%7E:text=driver%2C%2010))%0Aelement%20%3D-,wait.until,-(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.